# Yii2 password reset does not work

Tags: php, windows, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

I use Windows and Yii 2.0.13.1 and xampp with php7.1.4.
When logging in, I click on *reset it* link and i'm entering my email and send, I encounter this error:

> Swift_TransportException
>   Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.
>   ]

My common/config/main-local.php is:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
],
```

Other settings and files are in the default mode.
what is the problem? Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that in your config is missing the  transport config
eg: using gmail.com as transport   (you should choose the trasport available for your host)

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses

        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'yourmail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'your_password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'streamOptions' => [
                'ssl' => [
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                ],
            ]
        ],

    ],
```

Everything is right now

Comment: I add this code and result is this error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Then you have not the previous err  ,, so as suggested  you should configure the transport for a valid mail server  .. the smtp.gmail.com is just a suggestion  ..

Comment: I am testing on localhost, I forgot to say that

Comment: in local host you can use a valid gmail.com  email address ,...me too in localhost use a gmail.com config

Comment: Thanks but I'm amateur in this field,  what exactly should I do?

Comment: you have a gmail  address ?

Comment: Error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Comment: the error is related  to your ssl localhost config  .. and i can't help  .. youn should suppresses the check for your ssl credential  for mail  ..

Comment: @MHF  very good work ... bravo (not properly an amateur ... )